# Index Error in C# Logic Causing Error in Sending Data to Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having issues where my code is sending an index error where when the

> Datapoints.datasets.Count

is larger than the index then the data shows a error in the client. I'm having trouble restructuring this code to make it work.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
var DataPoints = new DataPoints();
        // Generate DataPoints (or something similar) from the newly constructed WspViewList.
        foreach (WspViewRow row in OriginalData)
        {
            var dataPointList = row.OriginalData.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').TrimEnd(',').Split(',').ToList();
            DataPoints.labels.Add(dataPointList[1]);

            for (var index = 2; index < dataPointList.Count; index++)
            {
                var dataPoint = dataPointList[index];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataPoint))
                    continue;
                ChartDataObject cdo;
                if (DataPoints.datasets.Count <= index - 2)
                {
                    cdo = new ChartDataObject();
                    DataPoints.datasets.Add(cdo);
                                    
                    cdo.label = ColumnObjects[index].propertyName;
                        cdo.label = "None";
                }
                else
                    cdo = DataPoints.datasets[index - 2];

                cdo.data.Add(dataPoint);
                DataPoints.datasets[index - 2] = cdo;
            }

            DataPointAPI DataPointResponse = new DataPointAPI()
            {
                data = DataPoints
            };
            dataset.Add(DataPointResponse);
        }
```

Comment: the max value of `index` is fixed at `dataPointList.Count - 1` and the `Datapoints.datasets.Count` is unknown and increased over time. So those 2 numbers don't have any constraints with each other, there is always a possible error as you has encountered. We can check the index before accessing the data first but I'm not sure what're you trying to do (about the algorithm) so it's hard to provide any advice here.

Comment: sometimes a wrong algorithm can require you to add a lot of checks for index accessing (just to ensure that there is no error thrown). That's why you need to understand your algorithm first, adding a check access here is just so simple. I mean if you understand your algorithm and you can explain when an index become out of bound (and that's just part of normal processing), then you can just add the check before accessing data via the index. Otherwise, consider adjusting your code to reflect the algorithm first.

Comment: i'm trying to fix the algorithm so the index error won't occur so Datapoint response object can be used

Comment: to avoid the exception is simple, but to avoid a wrong result produced by a wrong algorithm is hard, especially when we don't even know what you're trying to achieve (some kind of the problem description). Extracting back the algorithm and the problem from code is sometime impossible and usually hard (unless the code is ***just correct*** and working but here that's of course not the case).